# How to insert into separate tables result of aggregate SQL query

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with an index and I am executing a aggregate SQL query using sum
you can see what I am doing [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30271/4) in sqlfiddle.

```
Create table TX (
  i int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  x1 DECIMAL(7,3), 
  x2 DECIMAL(7,3), 
  x3 DECIMAL(7,3)
);


INSERT INTO TX (i,x1,x2,x3) values
(1,5, 6,6) ;
INSERT INTO TX (i,x1,x2,x3) values
(2,6, 7, 5);
INSERT INTO TX (i,x1,x2,x3) values
(3,5, 6, 7) ;
INSERT INTO TX (i,x1,x2,x3) values
(4,6, 7, 4);
```

My question is How can I insert into 3 different tables the results of that query?

```
SELECT SUM(1),
       SUM(x1),SUM(x2),SUM(x3),
       SUM(x1*x1),
       SUM(x2*x1),SUM(x2*x2),
       SUM(x3*x1),SUM(x3*x2),SUM(x3*x3)

FROM TX
```

so

how can I get something like

```
Sum(1)
-----
n

index  Sums
------------
1      4
2      22
3      26

index1  index2   Mult
----------------------
1            1   122
2            1   144
2            2   170
3            1   119
3            2   141
3            3   126
```

Instead of

```
    SUM(1) SUM(X1) SUM(X2) SUM(X3) SUM(X1*X1) SUM(X2*X1) SUM(X2*X2) SUM(X3*X1) SUM(X3*X2)  SUM(X3*X3)
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________
        4      22       26     22        122        144       170      119          141          126
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(1)
FROM TX;

SELECT 1, SUM(x1)
FROM TX
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, SUM(x2)
FROM TX
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, SUM(x3)
FROM TX;

SELECT a.x i1, b.x i2, SUM(a.s * b.s)
FROM
(
    SELECT i, 1 x, x1 s
    FROM TX
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT i, 2 x, x2 s
    FROM TX
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT i, 3 x, x3 s
    FROM TX
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT i, 1 x, x1 s
    FROM TX
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT i, 2 x, x2 s
    FROM TX
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT i, 3 x, x3 s
    FROM TX
) b ON a.i = b.i AND a.x >= b.x
GROUP BY a.x, b.x;
```

[SQL Fiddle using your data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30271/33) - Note that your data's sums (second query) do not match those in your question. I trust this is a typo.

Notice I got a bit lazy with the third query. Instead of writing out the expansion I flattened the table first and joined it on itself.

Also note that in the first query `SUM(1)` can be replaced with `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: I am afraid that is incorrect, for example look SUM(x3*x3) and is not the same 126, yours is 484

Comment: Ahh, sorry I missed you wanted the sum of the products, not the product of the sums

Comment: @cMinor Ok I fixed my third query

Answer (score 3):

Run 3 separate queries.  Turning the SELECTs into INSERTs depends on the RDBMS.  For SQL Server, it's just adding an `INTO newTableName` before the `FROM` clause to create a new one, or `INSERT INTO existingTableName` before the `SELECT` statement.

```
Create table TX (
  i int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  x1 DECIMAL(7,3), 
  x2 DECIMAL(7,3), 
  x3 DECIMAL(7,3)
);


INSERT INTO TX (i,x1,x2,x3) values
(1,5, 6,6) ;
INSERT INTO TX (i,x1,x2,x3) values
(2,6, 7, 5);
INSERT INTO TX (i,x1,x2,x3) values
(3,5, 6, 7) ;
INSERT INTO TX (i,x1,x2,x3) values
(4,6, 7, 4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS SUM1
FROM TX
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30271/17/0)**:

```
| SUM1 |
--------
|    4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT SUM(X1) index1, SUM(X2) sums
FROM TX
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30271/17/1)**:

```
| INDEX1 | SUMS |
-----------------
|     22 |   26 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT x.index1,
       x.index2,
       case x.id
       when 1 then SUM(x1*x1)
       when 2 then SUM(x2*x1)
       when 3 then SUM(x2*x2)
       when 4 then SUM(x3*x1)
       when 5 then SUM(x3*x2)
       when 6 then SUM(x3*x3)
       end Mult
FROM TX
CROSS JOIN
     (select 1 id, 1 index1, 1 index2 union all
      select 2 id, 2 index1, 1 index2 union all
      select 3 id, 3 index1, 1 index2 union all
      select 4 id, 2 index1, 2 index2 union all
      select 5 id, 3 index1, 2 index2 union all
      select 6 id, 3 index1, 3 index2) x
GROUP BY x.id, x.index1, x.index2
ORDER BY x.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30271/17/2)**:

```
| INDEX1 | INDEX2 | MULT |
--------------------------
|      1 |      1 |  122 |
|      2 |      1 |  144 |
|      3 |      1 |  170 |
|      2 |      2 |  119 |
|      3 |      2 |  141 |
|      3 |      3 |  126 |
```

Comment: Is there a way to do so in the same query maybe creating a VIEW and then executing a query

Comment: You can't produce *multiple* results sets per query?!

Comment: That is only possible in a large query like th original?

Comment: In SQL Server, you can create a procedure that will perform 3 selects. But it's not a `view`, which is just a stored query definition. It takes some front-end processing to iterate through the separate resultsets though.

Comment: can you please tell the way to do your query but in general? like for example 10 columns, not only 3?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. Is it a new question? I don't get the references to 10/3 columns.